# Why am I getting an error during a migration coupled with default data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

```
    rails g migration CreateStates
```

Then add the following code to the migration:

===========================

```
class CreateStates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :states do |t|
      t.column :name, :string
      t.column :abbreviation, :string
    end

    State.create :name => 'Alabama', :abbreviation => 'AL'
    State.create :name => 'Alaska', :abbreviation => 'AK'
    State.create :name => 'Arizona', :abbreviation => 'AZ'
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :states
  end
end
```

============================

I get an error:

** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
==  CreateStates: migrating ===================================================
-- create_table(:states)
   -> 0.0010s
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

uninitialized constant CreateStates::State
/Users/jondoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing'

========

It seems like this should be able to do this:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

I have also tried to create a model instead of a just a migration file. Still same error. I have also tried creating 2 migrations (one to create table, then one to add data) and that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably, there is no model State. Also, it is advised to put database population code into db/seeds.rb file.

Comment: Thanks Taro. There was a model naming inconsistency

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
State.reset_column_information
```

before your State.create.

[documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActiveRecord/Base/reset_column_information/class)

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work perfectly, except that you don't actually have a `State` class. The only way Rails would know about this class is if you defined it in `app/models/state.rb` as `Class State < ActiveRecord::Base...`

Rather than running a custom migration, I'd recommend running this line of code:

```
rails g model State name:string abbreviation:string
```

This will:

1. Create your model (and unit test files)
2. Create a migration named something like `20110508223913_create_states.rb`, which will look nearly identical to your attempted migration above.

Then all you need to do is add your `State.create...` lines and you should be good to go.